# Why is my XAML not responding to a change in a variable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

there is probably a really simple reason why this isnt working but I've tried everything. I have a TextBlock with Text bound to a variable, the variable changes but the Text doesn't :

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="modeLabel" Style="{StaticResource IndiTextBlock}"  Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ModeLabelText}" Margin="35,22,58,0"/>
```

The code that controls the text value is in a viewmodel:

```
public string ModeLabelText { get { return _modeLabeltext; } }
public ComboBoxItem SelectedMode { get { return _selectedMode; }
set
{
    if (_selectedMode == value) return;
    _selectedMode = value;
    ToggleMode(null);
    EvaluateScenario(null);
}
```

and

```
private void ToggleMode(object parameter)
{
    if (_isBasicCalculation)
    {
        _modeLabeltext = "Target profit";
        _isBasicCalculation = false;
    }
    else
    {
        _modeLabeltext = "Total to invest";
        _isBasicCalculation = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have set data context for it, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface, and on changes of your variables, you should trigger the event

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler PropertyChanged; // event from INotifyPropertyChanged

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var local = PropertyChanged;
        if (local != null)
        {
            local.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public void ToggleMode()
    {
        // ... your code ...
        RaisePropertyChanged("ModelLabelText");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Nguyen Kien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/753871/nguyen-kien)

```
    private void ToggleMode(object parameter)
    {
        if (_isBasicCalculation)
        {
            _modeLabeltext = "Target profit";
            OnPropertyChanged("ModeLabelText");
            _isBasicCalculation = false;

        }
        else
        {
            _modeLabeltext = "Total to invest";
            OnPropertyChanged("ModeLabelText");
            _isBasicCalculation = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Since it changes in both branches of the if, you could safely put the OnPropertyChanged method call behind the if :)